# Python: Copy a CSV file from one RPi to another

Tags: python, ssh

I have 2 Raspberry Pi's 3, running **Ubuntu Mate**.
On each RPi there is a CSV file to be read or copied ( depends if it master or not ).

A python code runs on RPI #1, and need to copy files from RPi#2 ( and read both as local file).

How can it be done usinh SSH ?

Comment: Check [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) for Python 2.7 or [Fabric3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3/) for Python 3.6.

Comment: That are several solutions to your problem, many of them on the OS level and out of scope for SO.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't understand your answer. I'm using ubuntu and I want to read the file using python, and not via OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too many options. But in general I'd shell out unless you have a good reason not to:

```
import subprocess
result = subprocess.run(['ssh', 'dude@otherpi', 'cat /var/lol/cats.csv'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result.check_returncode()
cats_csv = result.stdout
```

We're telling Python to run this command: `ssh dude@otherpi "cat /var/lol/cats.csv"`. So an `ssh` process will connect to `dude@otherpi` and run the command `cat /var/lol/cats.csv` on the remote. You can try this by just running the line in your shell. The output of this command is captured by Python, we've to configured this with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`. The call to `check_returncode` is just there to abort in case something goes wrong, like connection error or file not found.

Instead of immediatley capturing the entire CSV, you could also copy it over then open it locally. This would allow handling big files. Then the command would be `['rsync', 'dude@otherpi:/var/lol/cats.csv', '/tmp/cats.csv']`. Use `scp` if `rsync` is not available.

Comment: Firstly- Thanks! it works OK. 
Secondly- can you explain syntax and do you recommend to write it to local file ?

Comment: I've added an explanation. If you save it to a file, it must fit on your filesystem. If you pipe it into a variable, it must fit into RAM. It depends on how you're going to process it too.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful way, since it is not a big file- is copying it to local RPi.

```
 result=subprocess.run(['scp','guy@192.168.2.112:/home/guy/PythonProjects/schedule.csv','/home/guy/schedule_192.168.2.112.csv'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```